# Disabling sound on Android's Ongoing notification updating

Tags: java, android, push-notification, android-notifications

I have an `Ongoing` notification that shows Date and updates every minute inside a service. But in android 8 it plays sound in every update and users confused whats happening.

i set this:

```
builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW);
```

This disabled the sound but has a side effect. Updating the Date is not working too! I want to update Notification without any sound. how it is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your notification channel try to set the sound to null. Like so:

```
channel.setSound(null, null);
```

Comment: Thanks. It works! How about lower androids? i don't want to play any sound in any Android. What i have to do?

Comment: Glad to hear ! Dont forget to upvote :) For older versions try : builder.setSound(null).